# Install Windows 10 IoT on 3B+?

Tags: pi-3b+, windows-iot

I bought a 3B+ a few months back and have been experimenting with it with Raspbian, but I recently discovered it is possible to run Windows 10 IoT on it and since I am  mainly a C# developer, I want to at least try that. I registered for the Windows Insider program so I could download the "preview" install which is supposed to work (with limits) on the 3B+, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to actually get it onto an SD card (bought multiple Samsung EVO 32 GBs for this purpose).

There are older instructions out there that say to use an FFU file, but the aforementioned preview is an .iso, so that doesn't work.  Tom's Hardware has a page (dated Feb of this year, so that seemed promising) which referenced the 'Windows on ARM' installer, but that project has been archived off GitHub and is no longer available. The latter's page re-directs visitors to the 'WOA Deployer for Raspberry Pi', but the zip file download is missing files for one of the projects and it won't build (tried both Visual Studio 2017 and 2015).

So I have to ask if anyone has tried this *recently*, and if so, do you have any advice on how to actually accomplish this?

Please don't respond by telling me not to bother - I still intend to continue with Raspbian, but I would make progress much faster if I could get Win 10 IoT to work.

Additional detail - I tried using the Windows 10 'Mount' feature to mount the .iso file as a drive, but what it contained was only an '.msi' file, and executing that did not allow me to change the drive that Windows 10 would install to (so I couldn't point it to the SD Card's drive letter).

Comment: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-windows-10-iot-raspberry-pi-3 - I've followed that and it works (damn slow install though)

Comment: though, the link in that page is wrong ... download for the iot dashboard is now at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/iot-core/downloads and instructions are at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/iot-core/tutorials/quickstarter/devicesetup

Comment: Thanks - I managed to get the images onto the SD Cards (I used both 17744 and 17763) - now I need to scrounge up a LAN cable to attach the Pi to my PC; tomorrow project - afterward I'll post an update.

Comment: WOW! that was quick!! I swear when I created the SD image it took over 2 hours!!! But then, I am stuck in Australia with 100mbit "wet string between two tin cans" internet :p

Comment: Oh... I just checked what was on the cards and it is only 15.7 MB - something definitely went wrong!  I will try again tomorrow.

Comment: I don't know IoT for Pi, but rasbian has two partitions, a small one about 16MB then the rest of the card - so it may have worked! I can't recall what my card looked like after I created it - I have since stopped using IoT so I can't check now

Comment: So it turns out that IoT Dashboard formatted both cards as 4 separate volumes.  Unfortunately, the Pi 3B+ hung at the rainbow screen for both (the original Raspbian card still works fine, so it isn't an issue with the Pi).

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/tutorials/quickstarter/prototypeboards take a look at the notes on running on a RPi3B+ on there.

Comment: You need to install the ISO on your work computer. Then look in the installed folder (typically c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft IoT), and you'll see the FFU folder.

Comment: Hello, did you succeed to run Windows IoT on Rpi 3 B+ please ? I am stuck here

Comment: @gaston - sadly no- I gave up before finding success.